# React Native Sortable List JSX element class does not support attributes

Tags: react-native

I am using this library: https://github.com/gitim/react-native-sortable-list ("react-native-sortable-list": "0.0.24") which does not have a type definition so I use:
"@types/react-native-sortable-list": "^0.0.9".

I have the following component defined in a tsx file (typescript):

```
import SortableList from 'react-native-sortable-list'
import ....// others

interface Props {
    tasks: ITask[]
}
export default function TasksList(props: Props) {

    return (
        <SortableList
            data={props.tasks}
            renderRow={({ active, data, disabled, index, key }) => {
                return (
                    <View key={key}>
                        <Text>{data.name}</Text>
                    </View>
                )
            }}
        />
     )
}
```

The code works (the list gets rendered fine) but I get a Typescript error:

JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.ts(2607)
'SortableList' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its instance type 'SortableList<unknown, unknown>' is not a valid JSX element.
Type 'SortableList<unknown, unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 3 more.ts(2786)

[image: Error message]

I don't know how to make the error go away. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Visual Studio Code had Typescript version 4.1.5. Once I changed it to 3.9.9 the error message was gone!